# No such ServerPlugin: GremlinPlugin

Tags: python, neo4j, bulbs

I want put some data to `Neo4j` database using python script. I think [bulbflow](http://bulbflow.com/) can be easy way how to do that.

I have this little script from their homepage and docs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
g = Graph()
james = g.vertices.create(name="James")
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bulb.py", line 4, in <module>
    james = g.vertices.create(name="James")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/element.py", line 565, in create
    resp = self.client.create_vertex(data, keys=_keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 424, in create_vertex
    return self.create_indexed_vertex(data, index_name, keys=keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 1054, in create_indexed_vertex
    return self.gremlin(script,params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 384, in gremlin
    return self.request.post(path, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 131, in post
    return self.request(POST, path, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 186, in request
    return self.response_class(http_resp, self.config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 217, in __init__
    self.handle_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/neo4jserver/client.py", line 249, in handle_response
    response_handler(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bulbs/rest.py", line 39, in not_found
    raise LookupError(http_resp)
LookupError: ({'status': '404', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '833', 'server': 'Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)'}, '{\n  "message" : "No such ServerPlugin: \\"GremlinPlugin\\"",\n  "exception" : "PluginLookupException",\n  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLookupException",\n  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.extension(PluginManager.java:124)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:165)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)" ]\n}')
```

`bulbflow` and `Neo4j` is properly installed according to http://bulbflow.com/download/. `Neo4j` is running with default configuration and I am able to open `http://localhost:7474/`.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Thank you, FrostyX

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Neo4j 2.0 the gremlin plugin is no longer bundled. However you can easily build and install that on your own, see https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as @stefan said, as of Neo4j 2 you have to install the Gremlin Plugin manually on Neo4j Server. However, you can use Neo4j with the TinkerPop Rexster server -- Rexster comes installed with the latest Gremlin, and Bulbs works with either server.

See...

- Rexster Wiki: https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/wiki
- Rexster Download: https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/releases
- Bulbs Docs: http://bulbflow.com/api/bulbs/#id3
- TinkerPop Overview: http://www.tinkerpopbook.com/